# How to get the file size of a GridFS file in a mongodb collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, gridfs

So every time a file is uploaded using GridFS, metadata is attached to it http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection including the filesize.

I'm uploading files using carrierwave-mongoid gem and I have an index page where I list the names of the files and the files can be downloaded.

I need to get the file sizes of all of those files. My question is, how can I get the file size of every file? How can I grab that information, the information that is already in the gridfs file metadata through Ruby?

Comment: Not really a ruby user, but I think you can at least grab it from db.fs.files collection. The length property indicates the file length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the filesize is stored as `length` in the files collection according to the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#the-files-collection)

You will have to grab some identifiable piece of information from the file to access it in mongo. The mongo docs show using `filename: "<your_file_name>"`. To access it with the `file _id`-

```
myid = BSON::ObjectId.from_string("57898fa2b5e1b565d4b9b5c8")
result = fs_bucket.find(_id: myid).to_json
obj = JSON.parse(result)
puts obj
```

Then you can access it as normal json.